# self.SetToolBar() not working on Mac

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, plot, wxpython

From the matplotlib embedding examples http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx2.html, it's indicated that you should use the SetToolBar() method to get the toolbar to behave properly. I tried this and I get an error saying that this is not an attribute of a panel. Also, that code manages to generate a toolbar but when you use the zoom button it freezes the plot without doing any zooming in until you use the move button. I don't know why this happens to me on a Mac it was working just fine on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given example, if you just use the regular toolbar setting without the SetToolBar it works just fine.